# Changing Ctrl-Win-Alt keys to Win-Alt-Ctrl

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Coming from a Mac, the standard modifier keys on Linux (and Windows) are pretty irritating.

- I need my thumb to be able to hit control so I need to change <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>.
- I need the windows key out of the way so I need to change <kbd>Control</kbd> to <kbd>Windows</kbd>.
- I need alt in the middle so I need <kbd>Windows</kbd> to become <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I've tried to do this via the Keyboard Layout control panel but it doesn't seem to offer the right combination of options. I've also tried via xmodmap but it seems even adding one keysym breaks my return and escape keys for no reason known to me. I've searched around here but the only answers I can find involve swapping two keys rather than moving three around.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm - the English (macintosh) keyboard layout does not do what you want?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not using an Apple keyboard. I merely want to move some keys around on the standard PC keyboard I have.

Comment: You could always rearrange your hand...

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried adding `xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Super_L"` and `xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Control_L"` and `xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Alt_L"` (keycodes found using `xev`) to my ~/.bashrc where I have the rest of my xmodmaps, but it didn't take, oddly. That's the way I have redefined my right control to delete using `xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Delete"`.

Comment: @Sikora Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved your problem yourself, please post instructions as a new **answer** and not as an edit to your question. Thanks!

Comment: trying editing  /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc & /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin maybe

Answer (score 1):

The OP answered the question and posted the solution in the question.

I ended up solving this problem by remapping <kbd>Windows</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to Hyper in Keyboard Layout. I then used CCSM to remap the Unity dash key to Hyper. I also remapped things like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (which is now physically <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> if you're still following) to get a more Mac-like experience. I no longer have a <kbd>Windows</kbd> key but after the CCSM remapping I have no use for one.

Answer (score 0):

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open Compiz Config Settings Manager and go to Preferences

[image]

Under unity you can set your keyboard bindings.

See [this forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1775670) for details

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't what I want. I do want to literally remap the keys globally. For example, I want Super_L to continue to bring up the dash; I just want to change which key is Super_L.

Normally I'd think I'd be able to do this with xmodmap, but it seems that any attempt to do so ends up breaking escape, return, and other keys. I'm not sure if this is an Ubuntu-specific problem.